# Lifetime of variables and processes in IOS

Tags: ios

When I navigate away from an app, what happens to those active processes running. I haven't found the right information regarding subject, but when a user comes back to the app what can I expect? Will the active page continue running where it left off? Will my variables retain their values? If anyone can point in the right direction that would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot rely on the app not being killed by iOS. You need to look into topics such as State Restoration so that when your app is killed and then re-started it returns to the screens / state the user left it in. There are WWDC videos that can walk you through this.

Answer (score 0):

Roughly speaking: When your app goes to the background, you should at that point save the state of the application. Then one of two things will happen: *Either* your app just kept running and comes back to the foreground. *Or* your app will be killed without any warning, but this isn't visible to the user. When the user thinks your app comes back to the foreground, your app is actually started again and should restore the state that it saved.

For details, read Apple's documentation and look through the WWDC videos.